# textblock position and sizing

Tags: containers, margin, textblock

I'm new in WPF, implementing the application using MVVM pattern.
Border is container which contain path and textblock. textblock contain number. 
Width and height of border control binded with viewmodel property.
want to show textblock contain i.e. number in middle of border container and path object on left top side of border container.
how to set the position of textblock in middle of border control.

```
<Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#FF30333A" Width="{Binding Width}" Background="#FF1C2125"
                        Height="{Binding Height}"
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path  Name="starPath" Fill="Gray" Data="M 9,0 L 7,6 L 0,6 L 6,11 L 4,17 L 9,12 L 14,17 L 12,11 L 18,6 L 11,6 L 9,0">
                            </Path>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="2"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20"  Foreground="White" Background="Gray">
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Try this : 


<Border BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="#FF30333A" Width="{Binding Width}" background="#FF1C2125" Height="{Binding Height}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <Path Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="starPath" Fill="Gray" Data="M 9,0 L 7,6 L 0,6 L 6,11 L 4,17 L 9,12 L 14,17 L 12,11 L 18,6 L 11,6 L 9,0"/>

      <TextBloc Grid.Row="1" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="20"/>
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

So ? **does it works ?**

Comment: TextBlock doesn't have erticalContentAlignment & HorizontalContentAlignment property. I tried by below way